# how to set vscode Ctrl+Click go to definition file with alias feature

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, alias

I used to implement alias feature , like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
```

but this feature let vscode can't go to definition file by `Ctrl+Click`.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 17):

Create or edit a `jsconfig.json`/`tsconfig.json` file at the root of your project and add the "paths" option:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

[Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases)

Comment: finally I add vue page files path to the tsconfig.json `include` , this vue page files cant be identified by typescript.

Comment: Do you have the [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) (Vue 3) or [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) (Vue 2) extension installed?

Comment: @MattSchlosser thanks for the solution. I'm using Volar, but also have to use `jsconfig.json` with defined path alias `@/*` as you mentioned above, otherwise it doesn't work. Also I noted that import paths should have `.vue` extension e.g. `import componentA from '@/folder/componentA.vue`.