# Ctrl + click does not work with aliases path in VS Code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, alias, vscode-jsconfig

I'm using VS Code for my Vuejs project and I resolve the "src" path with "@", here is my config:
[image]

And here is where I use the import statement with "@"
[image]

The web runs fine but I cannot click to go to my file. Please help

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037875/how-to-set-vscode-ctrlclick-go-to-definition-file-with-alias-feature

Comment: Use .vue extension, it's safer and can make a difference in this case

Comment: @shivetay I tried, but sadly it did not work

Comment: @EstusFlask I tried this too but did not work as well